# unable to bintrayUpload HTTP 404 Subject was not found

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

I'm facing this error for long time:

> Execution failed for task ':lib-change-scene:bintrayUpload'.
>
> Could not create package 'RajuSE/change-scene/change-scene': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Subject 'R
>   ajuSE' was not found]

Sometimes this task even freezes on 98% and doesn't proceed.

Refer Issues​ I posted on github:
https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/189
https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/188

Update :  I'm able upload library using uploading zip solution.. it is has been approved.. but definitely looking for gradle way solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your username on bintray is rajuse all non capital letters.
But you still put an orgName with the value RajuSE.

If you are trying to upload to your user context than remove the orgName.

In Bintray you can upload content to either an organization or a user.

Please make sure your bintray username configuration are same (case sensitive) as your actual username.

Comment: I tried that thing too https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/188.. please check.. upload gets stuck at 98%..